# Changing links color make dropdown get cut

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have made a dropdown menu and I want to change the links's color but if I add:

```
a {
    color: white;
}
```

it makes the dropdown invisible even if I add to every div element the attribute

```
overflow: visible;
```

Why is that happening?

https://jsfiddle.net/mvetktg0/

Comment: white on white = invisible

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your white links will fall outside the dark grey background onto the white, which is why you can't see them. Consider these edits:

```
.link-container a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 40px 0 40px 0;
    color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-link {
    background: steelblue;
}
```

Comment: But it happens even if I'm writing `text-decoration: none`

Comment: `text-decoration:none;` removes the link's underline. it has nothing to do with white, invisible etc. text.

Comment: No, sorry, my bed it isn't :P
Never thought about the background-color though, thnaks!

Comment: No problem - don't forget to make the answer correct if it worked.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make the text invisible to me - just white. If you add:

```
a {
    background: #404040;
}
```

you'll see your white text better. Hope I could help! :)

Answer (score 2):

The following code should work for you:

text-shadow: 0 1px black;

Answer (score 1):

I've changed you're css a bit to make things more visible.

I changed the background color of your `body` and `dropdown-link`. Also I decreased the width of the image so It could all fit.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
  background:lightgrey;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
  color:white;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
}

.head-menu {
    background-color: #404040;
}

.image-container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
}

.image-container img {
    display: inline;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.link-container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.link-container a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 40px 0 40px 0;
}

.dropdown-link{
  background-color: gray;
}

.dropdown1-content {
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown2-content {
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown-link a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 0 5px 0;
}

.dropdown1:hover .dropdown1-content {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: inherit;
    z-index: 99;
}

.dropdown2:hover .dropdown2-content {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Can you plz comment next to what you have changed?

Comment: @omer I've added it to the answer